# How to redirect https to private port?

Tags: nginx, redirect, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an webserver with snap which run in http://example.com:3001 (it doesn't have support for https) so i'm using nginx proxypass together with cerbot to generate a certificate and it works great but i have two questions:

1.- This `https://example.com <--> nginx <--> http://example.com:3001` redirection is the correct way to do it?  I am not sure since it's still being posible to go directly to unsecure port 3001.

2.- It's posible to do this redirection in the host to avoid to open 3001 port to internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Port 3001 should not be exposed to the internet.

Comment: @Benjamin This isn't a redirection. This is proxying. You should use `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;` instead and that 3001 port shouldn't be open for anything except the localhost.